# Boxplot and remove outliers from large dataframe

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, data-cleaning, outliers

I have a dataframe (e.g. df_EDA) with 64 columns, how can i plot multiple boxplots and quickly identify the outliers and remove them?

As of now, when I run the boxplot: `sns.boxplot(data=df_EDA)`

It appears as follows:
[image]

Comment: You'll need a thorough definition for outliers, that works well for your data and the intended use case.   A one-size-fits-all solution doesn't exist.  Also, you'll probably don't want to put columns with values that have a very different range all together in one subplot.

Comment: It is likely, that the outlier is always be the first box. If this is the case just remove it.